# Google VM Instance becomes unhealthy on its own

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have been using Google Cloud for quite some time and everything works fine. I was using single VM Instance to host both website and MySQL Database.

Recently, i decided to move the website to autoscale so that on days when the traffic increases, the website doesn't go down.

So, i moved the database to Cloud SQL and create a VM Group which will host the PHP, HTML, Image files. Then, i set up a load balancer to divert traffic to various VM Instances under VM Group.

The problem is that the Backend Service (VM Group inside load balancer) becomes unhealthy on its own after working fine for 5-6 hours and then again becomes healthy after 10-15 minutes. I have also seen that the problem can come when i run a file which is a bit lengthy with many MySQL Queries.

I checked the Health check and it was giving 200 response. During the down period of 10-15 minutes, the VM Instance is accessible from it own ip address.

Everything is same, i have just added a load balancer in front of the VM Instance and the problem has started.

Can anybody help me troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your server is timing out (blocking?) on the health check during the times the load balancer reports it as down. A few things you can check:

1. The logs (I'm presuming you're using Apache?) should include a duration along with the request status in the logs. The default health check timeout is 5s, so if your health check is returning a 200 in 6s, the health checker will time out after 5s and treat the host as down.
2. You mention that a heavy mysql load can cause the problem. Have you looked at disk I/O statistics and CPU to make sure that this isn't a load-related problem? If this is CPU or load related, you might look at increasing either CPU or disk size, or moving your disk from spindle-backed to SSD-backed storage.
3. Have you checked that you have sufficient threads available? Ideally, your health check would run fairly quickly, but it might be delayed (for example) if you have 3 threads and all three are busy running some other PHP script that's waiting on the database